# How to use italics in titles?

Tags: title

How do I italicize words in the title? The title field does not have a formatting panel under it like the body field.

Comment: You'll get better answers to your questions if you provide some information about what version of EE (and any add-ons) you are using; the differences in EE versions can be significant factors in how the question is answered.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way within EE to italicise elements within a title string.

If you are looking to change the style of a word according to some pattern - e.g. to italicise the first word of the title regardless of what it says, or to italicise any use of the word "something" when ever it appears you would need to modify your site's CSS (and possibly add some Javascript) to achieve this result.

If you want the ability to add arbitrary rich text formatting to the string you are using for a title the only way to do this within EE is to use a different field to hold the title text you want to use (either a [text input field](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/text.html) set to accept Markdown formatting, or a [Rich Text field](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/rte.html)).

To make it less confusing for editors, you can [rearrange the CP fields and screens](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/control-panel/channels.html#form-layouts) for that channel to put your alternative title field close to the actual title field.

HTH